# Unable to use "Java Bindings Library" Project

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I have the latest MonoDevelop and MonoDroid. I am trying to create a wrapper around a Java library using a "Java Bindings Library" project. I followed the steps detailed by Xamarin at http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar) and built the MyGoogleMaps assembly from maps.jar.  MyGoogleMaps compiles without error, but when I referenced MyGoogleMaps from another project I don't see  any of its namespaces, classes or other members.

I even downloaded the sample code in that project and had the same problem.

Any ideas? If I can clarify please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Resharper?  I had this problem with Resharper and had to disable it and then intellisense kicked in correctly.